# Where can I find some useful current Access Tutorials?

Tags: microsoft-access-2010

I'm working an a research project and need to learn some of the basic and more intricate how to's of Access 2010.  Are there any free online resources that are worthwhile?

I'm looking to learn how to:

- Basics of access
- Build and develop Relationships
- Code basic operation in vBasic
- Building a GUI interface within Access
- Analysis of data (Statistics)
- Merging of databases

YouTube videos are ok, but I haven't found really any useful ones for newer versions so please don't post tutorials for the 2000 line of Access.  Also, please refrain from just posting a bunch of links.  Give a brief description of what the link contains for learning Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the best way I found was the sample applications/templates.

Click `File` > `New` and take a look - there are thousands online dealing with everything - some are rubbish to learn from, others have many comments and are interesting.

In addition, you can always read the help files, they are not designed to be an interesting book or help you build a database, but if you are stuck on a feature/function, you can usually find detailed instructions on what to do (with samples).

Lastly, if you are having trouble, you can always just get a book - I can't recommend any as the last Access book I had was 2002... but I suggest you read reviews from other users.